# What are functional languages most used for?

Tags: functional-programming

I wondered what functional languages are mainly used for? I've been reading about them and read about Haskell and others. Some seem to be just "academic" languages which makes little sense to me, so hoping to get a better idea of their uses in real world applications.

Comment: There are some good answers on stack overflow. Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602444/what-is-functional-declarative-and-imperative-programming

Ideally those should be moved here but we dont live in a perfect world.

Comment: I use [aura](https://github.com/fosskers/aura), but I'm not sure that's a typical example.

Comment: (un)Surprisingly enough, the most widely-used functional language is JavaScript.

Comment: what is a functionnal language for you?

Comment: @JitB Thanks for that, I thought that here was the better option for this question.

Comment: @DeerHunter is JavaScript a functional language? I've seen arguments that it isn't?

Comment: @simon I don't really know a huge amount about them. I've also noted that some descriptions of what constitutes a functional language is vague or not fully agreed on.

Comment: @Johnny: True. There are, however, some main ideas that recur in most functional languages: referential transparency, functions as first-class values, closures, higher-order functions, immutable data, use of recursion instead of iterative computation + side-effects, algebraic data types, pattern matching, ...

Comment: @Jonnny I just wanted to point out that without some kind of definition of a functional language, answers won't be very useful.

Comment: @Simon Agreed Simon, but I thought there would be a general consensus on the idea, although I know the minor points would create debate. I'd up vote your comment, but I can't yet.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @DeerHunter While JavaScript does support some of the features commonly used in functional languages, it's not really one (in that it's missing advanced FP features, it encourages side-effects and mutation, lacks referential transparency, etc.). I'd say JS is mainly an imperative language with some support for functional idioms instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Functional programming languages are really suitable for Big Data because if you think about it, most of Big Data is about data processing, filtering, aggregating (a.k.a Data Flow).

  Functional programming idioms such "Higher Order Functions", functions composition, partial functions, map/reduce, filtering, sequences abstraction (in Clojure) are a natural match to Big Data field.
- Functional programming languages make it easy to write "Domain Specific Language".
- Functional programming languages greatly simplify coding and architecting multithreaded and parallel systems (Erlang Actors, Elixir, Scala/Akka, Clojure/Pulsar).
- Functional programming languages are suitable to code "Natural Language Processing", "Information Retrieval" and "Machine learning" systems. This is also due the "Higher Order Functions".

The ability to create and return functions dynamically at runtime is the main reason why Lisp is used to create AI and machine learning systems.

Dean Wampler gave an interesting talk at the Lambda Jam conference on why [Copious Data is the Killer App for Functional Programming](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/big-data-functional-programming).

One field that I don't think functional programming fits in is building GUIs. This is where OOP shines. Just take a look at Cocoa and Cocoa Touch; both are well crafted frameworks.

Personally I like creating web applications with a functional programming languages. My favorite stack right now is Clojure/Pedestal/ClojureScript.

Comment: FRP is a wonderful way to build GUI's. Personally I enjoy it more than any OOP framework I've used so far

Comment: @chiron Thanks, as soon as I get enough reputation I will upvote/accept this answer and also upvote some other comments as they were helpful to me. I've yet to really delve into the area in much detail but it does seem interesting - Thanks

Comment: @jozefg: What language + framework are you using for FRP? I find this topic very interesting.

Comment: @Giorgio I use Reactive Banana which is in Haskell. I've heard good things about Racket's FRP DSL language as well. I don't like JS so I haven't touched any of those libraries

Comment: Great anwser except "Just take a look at Cocoa and Cocoa Touch" - I would take a look at WPF and Reactive Extensions instead: proper declarative + functional-reactive GUI. I am afraid Cocoa comes from previous age.

Comment: @Den Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are really well crafted frameworks but I'm going to dive into FRP for sure. Interesting stuff!

Comment: @Chiron also check MVVM and declarative GUI languages.